# .js variables not returning to zero when made equal to 0

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vue-component

I have various .js functions calculating order sub-totals, tax, and final total price in a modal. The calculations are correct, but the variables don't seem to be cleared on modal exit/modal pop-up. This means that every modal past the first one simply adds their (correct) calculations to the previous ones, rather than starting from zero as I'm trying to make it do.

I've set breakpoints in the .js source, and it tells me that the .js numbers are the one's not zeroing even when there is a set to zero on them right after the number is passed back.

Here is a picture set of the first and second modal call to illustrate this issue (bottom right numbers on both):

[image: first modal]
[image: second modal]

Here is my html, in case it's actually a tag-based issue:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<div class="col-sm-3">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="panel col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="panel-title text-center" style="padding-top:20px;">
        <h3 style="font-weight:bolder">Cart Contents</h3>
        <img src="/img/cart.png" style="height:10%;width:10%;padding-bottom:5%;" />
    </div>
    <div class="text-center" style="padding-top:10px;">
        @{
            Dictionary<string, object> cart = Context.Session.Get<Dictionary<string, Object>>("cart");
            decimal itemSubTotal = 0;
            decimal subTotal = 0;
            decimal itemTaxTotal = 0;
            decimal taxTotal = 0;
            decimal salesTaxRate = 0.13M; //m required for a literal
            decimal orderTotal = 0;



        }
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr style="font-weight:bolder;">

                <th class="col-xs-2 text-center">Product Code</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2 text-center">Qty</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2 text-center">Item Name</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2 text-center">Price</th>
            </tr>
            @{
                if (cart != null)
                {

                    foreach (var key in cart.Keys)
                    {
                        ProductViewModel item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
                        <ProductViewModel>
                        (Convert.ToString(cart[key]));

                        if (item.Qty > 0)
                        {

                            subTotal += item.MSRP * item.Qty;


                            <tr>
                                <td class="col-xs-2 text-center">@item.Id</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-2 text-center">@item.Qty</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-2 text-left">@item.ProductName</td>
                                <td class="col-xs-2 text-center">@string.Format("{0:C}", @item.MSRP)</td>
                            </tr>

                        }
                    }

                    taxTotal += Decimal.Multiply(subTotal, salesTaxRate);
                    orderTotal += subTotal + taxTotal;
                }
            }
        </table>
        <hr />
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" class="col-xs-4 text-left" style="font-size:large;font-weight:bold;">
                    Cart
                    Totals
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-2 text-right">Subtotal: </td>
                <td class="col-xs-4 text-left" id="subtotal">@string.Format("{0:C}", @subTotal)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-2 text-right">Tax Total: </td>
                <td class="col-xs-4 text-left" id="taxtotal">@string.Format("{0:C}", @taxTotal)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col-xs-2 text-right">Order Total: </td>
                <td class="col-xs-4 text-left" id="ordertotal">@string.Format("{0:C}", @orderTotal)</td>
            </tr>
            @{ 
                @subTotal = 0;
                @taxTotal = 0;
                @orderTotal = 0;
            }
        </table>
        <div class="text-center">
            <form asp-controller="Cart" asp-action="AddCart" method="post" role="form">
                @if (Context.Session.GetString(SessionVars.User) != null)
                {
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="modalbtn">Add Cart</button>
                }
                &nbsp;<a href="/Cart/ClearCart" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Clear Cart</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And here is the .js file where the calculations are being done:

```
   var link = '/GetOrders';
    var detailslink = '/GetOrderDetails/';
    var subtotal = 0;
    var finalPrice = 0;
    var taxAmount = 0;
    // register modal component
Vue.component('modal', {
    template: '#modal-template',
    props: {
        item: {},
        modalItem: {},
        details: []
    },
})
new Vue({
    el: '#orders',
    methods: {
        GetOrders: function () {
            var self = this
            axios.get(link).then(function (response) {
                self.orders = response.data;

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
        },
        loadAndShowModal: function () {
            var self = this
            axios.get(detailslink + this.modalItem.id).then(function (response) {
                self.details = response.data;
                self.showModal = true;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
        },
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.GetOrders();
    },
    data: {
        orders: [],
        showModal: false,
        modalItem: {},
        details: []
    }
});
function formatDate(date) {
    var d;
    if (date === undefined) {
        d = new Date(); //no date coming from server
    }
    else {
        var d = new Date(Date.parse(date)); // date from server
    }
    var _day = d.getDate();
    var _month = d.getMonth() + 1;
    var _year = d.getFullYear();
    var _hour = d.getHours();
    var _min = d.getMinutes();
    if (_min < 10) { _min = "0" + _min; }
    return _year + "-" + _month + "-" + _day + " " + _hour + ":" + _min;
}


function calcLinePrice(qtySold, msrp)
{

    var linePrice = qtySold * msrp;
    subtotal += linePrice;
    finalPrice += linePrice;
    return linePrice.toFixed(2);

    finalPrice = 0;
    subtotal = 0;

}

function calcSubtotal()
{

    return subtotal.toFixed(2);
    subtotal = 0;

    finalPrice = 0;
    subtotal = 0;
}

function calcTax() {

    taxAmount = finalPrice * 0.13

    return taxAmount.toFixed(2);
    taxAmount = 0;

}


function calcFinalPrice() {
    var total = 0;
    total = finalPrice + taxAmount;
    return total.toFixed(2);

    finalPrice = 0;
    subtotal = 0;

}
```

As you can see, I'm zeroing the finalTotal and subtotal in every calculation in an attempt to figure this out. It seems that no matter what I do, they refuse to zero on anything but page reload. Any help?

EDIT: I was attempting to zero at the wrong points. I solved this by altering my calcFinalPrice() function (being the last function) to this:

```
function calcFinalPrice() {
    var total = 0;
    total = finalPrice + taxAmount;
    taxAmount = 0;
    subtotal = 0;
    finalPrice = 0;
    return total.toFixed(2);


}
```

Comment: check the browser developer tools console (this is debugging 101) - you should see a message telling you what you're doing wrong - hint, it has to do with where in the function your `return` statement is

Comment: No code will be executed after `return` statement in current context

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm aware, I was using it to find the values of the variables in the .js to confirm it was a .js problem and not a tag issue. Thanks for the hint, I didn't realize that js functions don't continue to process internally past the return.

Comment: I was talking about the message along the lines of `unreachable code after return statement` - not your `console.log` messages :p ... nevermind, seems firefox is the only browser that provides this useful message

Comment: That's actually very useful information, I didn't realize it would have additional error checking functionality. Perhaps I'll try debugging in firefox as a part of my process as well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning before re-assigning "0" to the variables. Use return after reassigning the values.

Comment: Right, but how can I pass back the calculated value if the only way to clear it for the next modal is to zero it before it gets returned? I tried making a holder variable that I zero at the beginning of the function, but it just has the same problem on the holder variable now.

Comment: instead of using global vars, use props, that will help. :)